# Homework question on identifying a key from a V triad

Tags: theory, chords, harmony

I am working through the ABRSM Discovering Music Theory Grade 4 book.  I appear to have found an unanswerable question, unless I have misunderstood something.  It's Section 7, Exercise 3, question k, on page 49 of the book.

Section 7 is about the tonic (I), subdominant (IV) and dominant (V) triads of the different keys.  Exercise 3 has the reader identifying the key (including major or minor), given one or more of those triads.

Question k gives only the V triad.  It is `A, C#, E`.  So it must be a D key.  If it's D major, then the C should be sharped, and it is.  If it's D minor, then the 7th should be raised a semitone, which makes the C a C#, which it is.

Am I missing something, or is the V triad of D major the same as the V triad of D minor?

Comment: What is the purpose of homework: to make you get correct answers and score points, or ... to make you work on and think about things? :)

Comment: @piiperiReinstateMonica - that's one of the best things I've had to cogitate on all week - but it's only Wednesday! Spot on!

Comment: Who says the C in key D minor isn't already sharpened? It is looking at melodic and harmonic minor scales.

Comment: @Tim The guidance around the questions seems to gloss over the melodic and harmonic minors, but suggests looking for a sharpened 7th to tell if a key is minor.

Comment: All the discussion and answers here are valid. However, the answer the exam board are looking for is D major.

Answer (score 6):

You are correct. It can be both D major and D minor. I know this may be a bit unsatisfying, but I verified the answer by looking at the answer book for your textbook. Nice catch!

Answer (score 3):

The **V** of any key will be major (with M3). It's often the case with minor keys - it makes a proper leading note, one semitone below the tonic. If, in key Dm, the C is C♮, then it would be represented in RN as **v**. That's not really in the remit of grade IV, for that question.

So the answer could be either - although if it's D minor, iv (not IV) will have to be G minor.